# Side-by-side figures with pseudocode in fboxes of same height

Tags: subfloats, fbox

I have two pieces of pseudocode that I want to be in side-by-side figures, encapsulated each in their own fbox and these fboxes should have the same height. Any advice on how to do this? I'm pasting my current code below (which doesn't work) together with a screenshot of what it looks like.

```
 \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
      {\footnotesize
        \parbox{2.2in} {
          \underline{\texttt{MJRTY}}:\\
          \textbf{initialize$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.1in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
          \item[1.] $i \leftarrow \bot$
          \item[2.] $C\leftarrow 0$
          \end{itemize} 
          
          \textbf{update$(j)$.} \texttt{// process item $j$ in stream}
          \vspace{-.4in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
            \medskip
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{if} $i=j$:
          \item[] \qquad $C\leftarrow C+1$
          \item[2.] \textbf{else}:
          \item[] \qquad $C\leftarrow \max\{0, C-1\}$
          \item[3.] \qquad \textbf{if} $C=0$:
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $i\leftarrow j$
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $C\leftarrow 1$
          \end{itemize}
          
          \textbf{query$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.2in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{return} $i$
%            \item[] \phantom{ }
          \end{itemize}
          
        }}\end{minipage}}
    \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{MJRTY}.}\label{fig:mjrty}
  \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}                                                                                                 
      {\footnotesize
        
        \parbox{2.2in} {
          \underline{\texttt{Frequent}}:\\
          \textbf{initialize$(k)$.} 
          \vspace{-.1in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
          \item[1.] $i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\leftarrow \bot$
          \item[2.] $C_1,\ldots,C_{k-1}\leftarrow 0$
          \end{itemize} 
          
          \textbf{update$(j)$.} \texttt{// process item $j$ in stream}
          \vspace{-.4in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
            \medskip
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{if} $\exists r$ such that $i_r=j$:
          \item[] \qquad $C_r\leftarrow C_r+1$
          \item[2.] \textbf{else}:
          \item[] \qquad \textbf{for} $r=1,\ldots,k-1$:
          \item[] \qquad\qquad $C_r\leftarrow \max\{0,C_r-1\}$
          \item[3.] \qquad \textbf{if} $\exists\ r$ such that $C_r=0$:
          \item[] \qquad\qquad pick such $r$ arbitrarily
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $i_r\leftarrow j$
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $C_r\leftarrow 1$
          \end{itemize}
          
          \textbf{query$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.2in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{return} $\{i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\}\backslash\{\bot\}$
          \end{itemize}
        }}\end{minipage}}
    \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{Frequent}.}\label{fig:frequent}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{MJRTY} and \textsf{Frequent}.}
      
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: minipage has an optional argument to specify the height of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the height of the minipage using the optional argument (5cm here) as shown the code is all overprinting as you have reduced the item sep and starting from the default values this makes the item separation negative, but presumably this was correcting code you have not shown. I left it as it is not relevant to the question about box height.

[image]

I guessed you are using `subcaption` to define `subfigure`, you did not say, and the `subfigure` package give syntax errors on your test fragment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{1cm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][5cm]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
      {\footnotesize
        \parbox{2.2in} {
          \underline{\texttt{MJRTY}}:\\
          \textbf{initialize$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.1in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
          \item[1.] $i \leftarrow \bot$
          \item[2.] $C\leftarrow 0$
          \end{itemize} 
          
          \textbf{update$(j)$.} \texttt{// process item $j$ in stream}
          \vspace{-.4in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
            \medskip
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{if} $i=j$:
          \item[] \qquad $C\leftarrow C+1$
          \item[2.] \textbf{else}:
          \item[] \qquad $C\leftarrow \max\{0, C-1\}$
          \item[3.] \qquad \textbf{if} $C=0$:
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $i\leftarrow j$
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $C\leftarrow 1$
          \end{itemize}
          
          \textbf{query$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.2in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{return} $i$
%            \item[] \phantom{ }
          \end{itemize}
          
        }}\end{minipage}}
    \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{MJRTY}.}\label{fig:mjrty}
  \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][5cm]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}                                                                                                 
      {\footnotesize
        
        \parbox{2.2in} {
          \underline{\texttt{Frequent}}:\\
          \textbf{initialize$(k)$.} 
          \vspace{-.1in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
          \item[1.] $i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\leftarrow \bot$
          \item[2.] $C_1,\ldots,C_{k-1}\leftarrow 0$
          \end{itemize} 
          
          \textbf{update$(j)$.} \texttt{// process item $j$ in stream}
          \vspace{-.4in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-3mm}
            \medskip
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{if} $\exists r$ such that $i_r=j$:
          \item[] \qquad $C_r\leftarrow C_r+1$
          \item[2.] \textbf{else}:
          \item[] \qquad \textbf{for} $r=1,\ldots,k-1$:
          \item[] \qquad\qquad $C_r\leftarrow \max\{0,C_r-1\}$
          \item[3.] \qquad \textbf{if} $\exists\ r$ such that $C_r=0$:
          \item[] \qquad\qquad pick such $r$ arbitrarily
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $i_r\leftarrow j$
          \item[] \qquad \qquad $C_r\leftarrow 1$
          \end{itemize}
          
          \textbf{query$()$.} 
          \vspace{-.2in}\begin{itemize}
            \addtolength{\itemsep}{-2mm}
            \smallskip
          \item[1.] \textbf{return} $\{i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\}\backslash\{\bot\}$
          \end{itemize}
        }}\end{minipage}}
    \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{Frequent}.}\label{fig:frequent}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Pseudocode for \textsf{MJRTY} and \textsf{Frequent}.}
      
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for such a noob question..indeed, setting the height for the minipages fixed things for me.

Comment: @JelaniNelson no problem but next time please provide a complete test document, not just a fragment